# PropertyEditor in java beans are stateful?

Tags: spring, javabeans, spring-mvc-initbinders

While understanding data binding in Spring i came to know that PropertyEditors are stateful , what is meant by stateful here ?

Here is the link of that docs

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/CustomEditorConfigurer.html

Answer (score 0):

**stateful** means that whenever you change the object (e.g. setting the value of a member with a set() method) these changes are persistent. The next time when you use your PropertyEditor it will have the same state as before - there framework will not create a new Instance of your PropertyEditor class for every request.

Comment: It means it  remembers what was the last value of the property